# Getting String value from MediaPlayer raw element

Tags: android, string, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I'll explain:

I have a .mp3 file in /raw called **R.raw.s_a**, and I want a variable with **"s_a"** as value.
How can i do that?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity:

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

or

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `raw` folder under `res` folder, and than copy mp3 file in `raw` folder

```
public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.s_a);
}
```

For more details, please refer [here](http://javapapers.com/android/how-to-play-audio-in-android/).

Comment: But here there's no assignment for a String value for that variable... I guess

Comment: It's not String value, it's a int, stand for ID